# Realised careless mistakes on application form - should I ask HR to update?

Tags: recruitment

Please read before you comment:
So I submitted an application form for a graduate scheme, did an online test and was invited to the interview as the next stage. As I review my application form submitted, I realise I described one of my old work experience in present tense, whereas the rest were in past tense. There was also a mistake with one symbol. These highlight a lack of attention to detail.

The question is, should I inform HR and submit a new application form?
Since the time of the application, I have gained more work experience and since left my recent job, so there is indeed reason to update the form re my work experience. Does this serve as a valid excuse to submit a new application form?

Please also note that there is an online portal. There is the option to upload new documents and removing old ones. I have uploaded the new updated one, so currently both forms are in the portal. I am fingers crossing that the interviewer will be referring to the updated application form when interviewing me. My question is should I inform HR that since I have an update on my work experience, I updated my application form and ask them to refer from that from now on?

Answer (score 3):

I would upload the new resume (which you have seemed to do) and delete the old one. If anyone asks you about it, I would just say that you further updated your resume since you applied and wanted to make sure that they had the most recent version.

I don’t think you should contact HR, or otherwise draw attention to the change. It doesn’t seem like there is a significant benefit to doing so, and drawing attentions to mistakes (especially ones caused by carelessness) is rarely the right move for job applications.

I would bring a hard copy of your most recent resume to the interview. I think that this is generally good practice, but also in this case it’s particularly helpful if the recruiter has read the old one and not the new one. It should rapidly become clear if they know where you currently work, and you can briefly explain that you had uploaded an updated resume but that it must have not crossed be recruiter’s desk. Apologize, pull out the new one, point out the major difference (“I left WidgetCo in April and now work at ConsultingExperts”), and continue with the interview.

**Note:** A major exception to this advice is if you are in contact with a recruiter or a hiring manager throughout the whole process. It doesn’t sound like that’s the case, but if it is then definitely **tell that person**. A short email explaining that you had an updated resume that you uploaded should suffice. Not doing so can look very weird, as if you’re trying to go behind their back or hide something from them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The benefit would be that if they accepted the new form, that form will be printed and referred to during the interviews by both HR and the partners, thus minimising the chances that they noticed any mistakes on my form.

Comment: @magenta333 It depends on how large the company is and what it’s SOP is, but my understanding is that at many companies resumes aren’t read by the interviewer or printed until the day of the interview. I think that the negative effect of emailing HR is more likely and worse than the positive effect.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I did not actually start at a new company. What I meant was I finished my work experience at the previous place, and I had MORE experience there (so I could now elaborate my tasks and duties further). Given the above, would your opinion still stand or should I approach the issue differently? Thanks again!